# Change barbutton image

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I try change my barbutton image when user load image from photoLibrary or camera. But my barbutton image all time resize and make very big. How i can fix that?

[image]

[image]

I try use outlet. And here my code

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        self.imageData = image.pngData()!

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.setImage(UIImage(data: imageData!), for: .normal)

        photoBarButton.customView = button


        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

If i try make something like this:

```
photoBarButton.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

i get [image]

Comment: Could you please add `UIBarButtonItem` init method?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var photoBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resize picked image first. Add below function to resize image:

```
extension UIImage {

    func resizedImage(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        guard size != newSize else { return self }

        let hasAlpha = false
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.0
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, !hasAlpha, scale)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)

        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Add above extension in your code and try to set image in `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
addAppointmentButton.image = pickedImage.resizedImage(newSize: CGSize(width: 24, height: 24))?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You my hero. Thx a lot =)